# Unable to instantiate subclass of WakefulIntentService as a receiver

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I'm implementing a datalogger service using WakefulIntentService and AlarmManager. I'm having trouble instantiating the receiver, however. Here's what I'm getting when I try to run the app.

> ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3181): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver my.package.WakefulLoggerIntentService: java.lang.InstantiationException: my.package.WakefulLoggerIntentService

Here's the relevant parts of the service class:

```
public class WakefulLoggerIntentService extends WakefulIntentService
{
   public WakefulLoggerIntentService()
   {
      super("WakefulLoggerIntentService");
   }

   @Override
   protected void doWakefulWork( Intent intent )
   {
      // Do the actual data logging.
   }
}
```

I've added receiver element to my manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".WakefulLoggerIntentService">
</receiver>
```

And here's the part that uses AlarmManager to schedule the logging events:

```
  Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), WakefulLoggerIntentService.class);
  PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);
  AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
  am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 30000, pi);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WakefulLoggerIntentService` is a `Service`. It is not a `BroadcastReceiver`.

To use `WakefulIntentService`, you need a `BroadcastReceiver` that is triggered by the alarm and, in turn, calls `sendWakefulWork()` to kick off your `WakefulLoggerIntentService`.

Also, you need to have your `WakefulLoggerIntentService` be registered in the manifest as a `<service>`, not a `<receiver>`.

Comment: That was the missing link. Thank you!